# What's the difference between 确实, 的确, and 实在?

Tags: meaning, difference

They all seem to have the same meaning. What's the difference between them? Thank you.

Comment: I already asked this question a while back: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/9920/3561

Answer (score 1):

I think the level are different.

他的确很帅 = He is very handsome, indeed.

他确实很帅 = He is very handsome, indeed.

他实在是帅 = How handsome he is!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. 确实

   1) adj. correct and true; "确(correct; exact)" + "实(true; real)"
   2) adv. correctly and truely.
2. 的确

   1) adj. = 确实; no doubltable.
   2) adv. indeed
3. 实在

   1) adj. honest; dependable
   2) adj. truely existed
   3) adv. in fact, really and truely

Answer (score 0):

实在 can also mean 'realistic' in the sense of a person being down to earth and practical.  A sentence like 那姑娘好实在，对男人的要求就是有车有房。is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

你确實帥

= 你實在帥

= 你的確帥

= you really handsome

= you are handsome

= you actually handsome.

No big difference.

I come from China, trust me.