# What's the difference between 确实, 的确, and 实在?

Tags: meaning, difference

I never understand the difference between these three words, and nobody has never been able to explain it to me. I searched about it on many books, and websites, but I just didn't get it. Can you please try to explain it to me? Thank you.

Comment: You've asked the same question [here](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/13614/4072)...

Comment: ... and I already asked this before that one: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/9920/3561

Comment: @songyuanyao @ Ming Why didn't either of you vote for dupe?

Comment: @NS.X. Just want to confirm what are OP thinking about...

Answer (score 2):

Let's first focus on their usages as adverbs. Adjective meanings are different.

A. As adverbs, 的确 and 确实 are the same. They mean 'indeed': without any question

- used in response to a statement that is regarded as doubtful or surprising
- used when making a statement that adds to or strengthens a previous statement

For example, "A: 你会给朋友推荐这本书吗？B: 没错，我(的确／确实／真的)会给朋友推荐这本书。" （A: Would you recommend this book to your friends? B: Yes, I will indeed recommend this book to my friends.)

B. As an adverb, 实在 means really/very: — used to refer to what is true or intensive (the latter is not in 的确／确实):

- without question or doubt
- to a great degree

For example, you can say "实在漂亮". It just means really/very beautiful.

In summary, to say 'in fact or indeed', you can use any of 的确, 确实 and 实在. But to mean 'really / very', you can only use 实在.

For example, 
After watching the movie, I think it is indeed a good one. 看完电影以后，我觉这(的确／确实／实在)是部不错的电影。

After I won a free movie ticket, I was really really happy. 赢得了免费的电影票，我实在是太高兴了. (but not 的确／确实)

Hope it helps a bit. As adjectives, they are also different but less subtle.

Comment: thank you! this helped A LOT! it's much easier than I thought! really thank you! I have struggled with these 3 words since forever

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad it helped. I feel sorry that very few dictionaries gave good explanations about these words.

Answer (score 0):

loredana castagna 你很实在，“What's the difference between 的确，确实 and 实在” 这个 的确（确实）是个比较难解释的问题。 而我也是个实在人，的确（确实）在认真回答你的问题。

Comment: additional information：
＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂相关条目［不同］２。＂实在＂可以用在当面表示歉意或感谢的句子里，加强语气；＂的确、确实＂很少这样用：１。是我搞错了，把你的东西给了他，实在对不起！（的确✔ 确实✔ ）２。你辛苦了，实在太谢谢你了！（的确✔ 确实✔ ）４。＂确实、实在＂都可以作定语、谓语，但意思不同：＂确实＂表示真实可靠，多用于事物，不能受＂不、很、非常＂等副词修饰；＂实在＂表示真实、不虚假，多用于人，可以受＂不、很、非常＂等副词修饰：１。没有确实的证据不要乱说。（的确✕实在✕）２。你说的这个消息确实吗？（的确✕实在✕）３。李力是个很实在的小伙子。（的确✕确实✕）４。李力的爸爸希望他学个实在的技术。（的确✕确实✕）５。张先生太客气，不实在。（的确✕确实✕）